# Convert to associative array PHP

Tags: php, arrays, associative-array

If you have this data:

```
1=Books
1.1=Action & Adventure
1.2=Arts, Film & Photography
1.2.1=Architecture
1.2.2=Cinema & Broadcast
1.2.3=Dance
```

The number on the data is the index. How can you put it in associative array? I want to know an example of associative array with that data. Thanks

Comment: Explode on `=` make the LHS indexes and RHS values

Comment: any depth of that array?

Comment: Yes. I want to see the associative array, Just comment your answer so i can image what I will do to other data like that. thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can be done with [explode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) and [foreach](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php)

**Steps:**

1) First explode the string with new line character `\n`.

2) Loo over it.

3) You will get individual row, explode() it with `=`.

4) You will get required key in `0` and value in `1`.

5) Store it in array as key value pair. **Done**

```
$str = '1=Books
1.1=Action & Adventure
1.2=Arts, Film & Photography
1.2.1=Architecture
1.2.2=Cinema & Broadcast
1.2.3=Dance';
$arr = explode("\n", $str);
$assoc = array();
if (! empty($arr)) {
 foreach ($arr as $k => $v) {
  $temp = explode('=', $v);
  $assoc[$temp[0]] = $temp[1];
 }
}
echo '<pre>';print_r($assoc);echo '</pre>';
```

**Output:**

```
Array
(
 [1] => Books
 [1.1] => Action & Adventure
 [1.2] => Arts, Film & Photography
 [1.2.1] => Architecture
 [1.2.2] => Cinema & Broadcast
 [1.2.3] => Dance
)
```

Comment: How about 1.1, 1.2, 1.2.1, 1.2.2, 1.2.3 is under in 1, i mean inside the array of books? Thanks

Comment: It will work the usual way. The provided code is capable of doing so.

Comment: It's okay if you don't the code, I just want to see the output.

Answer (score 1):

Can be done by converting string into `query string` format and then use [parse_str()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-str.php)
have to insert 1.0 => Books (append.0)
and 1.2.0 => Arts, Film & Photography (append .0)

```
 $str = '1.0=Books
    1.1=Action & Adventure
    1.2.0=Arts, Film & Photography
    1.2.1=Architecture
    1.2.2=Cinema & Broadcast
    1.2.3=Dance';<br />
    //replace & with and because parse_str not work with '&'
    $str = str_replace('&','and',$str);
    $str_ar = explode("\n",$str);
    foreach($str_ar as $line){
        $aar .= 'a';
        $line_ar = explode('=',$line);
        $array_index = explode('.',$line_ar[0]);
        foreach($array_index as $index){
            $aar .= '['.$index.']'; 
        }
        $aar.='='.($line_ar[1]).'&';
    }
    $aar = rtrim($aar,'&');
    parse_str($aar,$o);
    $o=array_shift($o);
```

**Output**

```
Array
(
    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => Books
            [1] => Action and Adventure
            [2] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Arts, Film and Photography
                    [1] => Architecture
                    [2] => Cinema and Broadcast
                    [3] => Dance
                )

        )

)
```